# Get Recent documents folder in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the path of recent documents folder using C#?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See:

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent
```

So:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(
    System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent)
);
```

Comment: +1, though the DirectoryInfo thing may be unnecessary if he just needs the path :)